# Automapper: Map to Unknown Destination / GetAllTypeMaps missing in latest Build

Tags: c#, automapper

Tested with: Automapper 10.1.2-alpha.0.4 (MyGet Build)

We want to map our DomainEvents to public Contracts that do not have any base classes and publish them to a Message Queue/Topic.

As it should be a dynamic mapping, we do not know the target type while the mapping to the destination contract occurs.

For that case, we had the following solution of this Post:
[How can I use Automapper to map an object to an unknown destination type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866425/how-can-i-use-automapper-to-map-an-object-to-an-unknown-destination-type) as follows:

```cs
public async Task Publish(DomainEvent domainEvent)
{
    this.logger.LogInformation("Publishing domain event. Event - {event}", domainEvent.GetType().Name);

    try
    {
        var publicEvent = this.MapToContract(domainEvent);

        await this.publishEndpoint.Publish(publicEvent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.LogError("Unexpected exception while publishing domain event.", ex);
    }
}

private object MapToContract(object source)
{
    var sourceType = source.GetType();
    TypeMap? typeMap = null;

    try
    {
        typeMap = this.mapper.ConfigurationProvider
            .GetAllTypeMaps()
            .SingleOrDefault(map => map.SourceType == sourceType);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Multiple types for {sourceType.FullName} available. Only one allowed");
    }

    return typeMap is null
        ? throw new Exception($"No type map for {sourceType.FullName} found!")
        : this.mapper.Map(source, sourceType, typeMap.DestinationType);
}
```

`Publish(DomainEvent domainEvent)` gets called as event receiver whenever an domain event is raised.

Since the last version, we can't use the `MapToContract` method anymore because the `GetAllTypeMaps` method is not available. I was not able to find any workaround.

Sample of the public event class:

```cs
public record EmployeeCreated(int Id, string Name, string FirstName);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/upgrade_guide/docs/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.md).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, had the same problem.
Solution is to use the internal extension method as follows (see https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=internal#forallmaps-forallpropertymaps-advanced-and-other-missing-apis):

```cs
using AutoMapper.Internal;

...

this.mapper.ConfigurationProvider
   .Internal()
   .GetAllTypeMaps()
   ...
```